# 自身のApacheでphpが動作している設定の把握、及びhtml拡張子でphp動作の達成に向けて

Tags: php, apache

皆様のご支援のもとお蔭様で　拡張子をphpとしたファイル群から一つのサイトが仕上がりつつあります。
当方は参考書片手にphpの拡張子で作り始めたのですが
いざ公開するとなると、これらをhtmlの拡張子に変更した上でリリースしたいと考え出しました。

達成したいことそのものの記事がhttps://eng-entrance.com/php-basic-extensionで紹介されておりましたので、参考にさせて頂きましたが
当方の端末（開発環境用Webサーバ）が、設定が異なっているらしく、対応手順の最初から躓いてしまいました。

【躓いた事象】
Apacheのhttpd.confやphp.confのファイルに、AddHandler phpX-script .phpの記述がある筈との言及だが、当方のhttpd.confにその記述がない。
（XAMPPだよりで一括インストールし、どうやってphpを動作させるようにしたか記憶がない、また自身の端末にphp.confというファイルは見当たらない）

====質問====
標題のとおりでございますが、自身のApacheでphpが動作している根拠は　どの設定に由来したものと考えられるか？（あとどの部分を確認すべきか？）、
またそちらの部分に対して記事に紹介された記述を（.htmlの併記）を行えば、今回の目的を達成できるのか　ご教示を頂けませんでしょうか？何卒よろしくお願い申しあげます。

PS:　現状.htmlに拡張子変更したページはphp非動作で画面が現れます（レンダリング＆リクエストからphp非動作と判断）。

Comment: 正直、「XAMPPだよりで一括インストールし、どうやってphpを動作させるようにしたか記憶がない」で済まされてはどうしようもありません。例えば「xampp php conf」で検索するだけで、[こんな記事](https://www.adminweb.jp/xampp/php/index3.html)がひっかります。(他にも多数ヒットします。)あなたの環境に関することはあなたが責任を持ってきちんと調べていただかないと、なかなか的確なアドバイスは得られないでしょう。XAMPPコントロールパネルの起動もできないのでしょうか?

Comment: 一寸前に、「Apacheの再インストールに挑戦中...」とか質問していたのに、ローカルのApache設定ぐらいカットアンドトライして、基本的な設定や動作の確認をすることを勧めます。

Comment: 解決したのでしょうか？もし上記コメントが解決内容でしたら自己回答をして承認して下さい。

Comment: @Myaku お蔭様で解決致しました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOperさん紹介のページhttps://www.adminweb.jp/xampp/php/index3.htmlでxamppを利用したApache上のPHP動作設定を おさらいすることができました。 html拡張子でもphpを動作させるための設定は、Apacheのhttp.confに以下2行を追加することで目的を達成することができました。 お時間を頂戴してしまい申し訳ございませんでした。 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html